# Вложенные SVG в другой SVG с выравниванием по центру

Tags: html, css, svg

Мне нужно поместить иконки SVG произвольной формы, то есть не обязательно квадратные, поверх SVG  маркера.

Я могу легко разместить их, но я не знаю, как их выравнивать относительно  внешней формы иконки маркера  по вертикали и горизонтали.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Маркер SVG**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="45">
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
    <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
    <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Иконка SVG:**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><title>bicycle</title><path d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/></svg>
```

**С наложением иконки (неправильное выравнивание):**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="45">
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
    <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
    <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
    <g fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero">
      <path d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Nesting SVGs with center alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56419550/7394871) от участника  [@eozzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172637/eozzy).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56419550/7394871

Comment: `Это очень просто`, - отвечает мастер SVG `@Paul LeBeau` Для него просто, а для изучающих SVG очень полезен его ответ, который показывает, как можно совместить и позиционировать два изображения SVG.  Не надо мучиться, создавая комбинированные изображения в векторном редакторе, получая на выходе ужасный код.

Comment: Посмотрите второй ответ - он более универсальный, так как комбинированные иконки можно использовать многократно с одновременным позиционирование

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый ответ хорош своей оригинальностью, но при таком решении комбинированную иконку
можно использовать только один раз. Так как разные части составной иконки лежат в разных  svg, то не получается клонировать иконки с помощью команды `<use>`

- А если потребуется использовать иконки многократно, в качестве
  маркеров на карте?

Тогда придется использовать другое решение для позиционировании составных частей иконки относительно друг друга.

Это можно сделать с помощью команды `transform="translate(2.5 2)"`

- Добавляем растровую карту в svg

`<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylp6r.png" width="100%" height="100%" />`

- Клонируем и одновременно позиционируем иконки на карте

`<use x="300" y="110" xlink:href="#bicicle" />`

Ниже полный код:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 960 761">
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylp6r.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
  <defs>
  
  <g id="bicycle">
      <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
    
      <path transform="translate(2.5 2)" fill="#fff" d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/>
    
  </g>
  </defs>  
     <use x="300" y="110" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="650" y="200" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
    <use x="650" y="450" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="150" y="250" xlink:href="#bicycle" />   
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

При клонировании значков их можно стилизовать.

Для этого удаляем атрибут `fill="#006893"` у родителя и раскрашиваем детей в разные цвета:

`<use x="300" y="110" fill="red" xlink:href="#bicycle" />`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 960 761">
   
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylp6r.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
        </filter>
  <g id="bicycle">
     <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
      <path  fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
    
      <path transform="translate(2.5 2)" fill="#fff" d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/>
    
  </g>
  </defs>  
     <use x="300" y="110" fill="red" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="650" y="200" fill="dodgerblue" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
    <use x="650" y="450" fill="purple" xlink:href="#bicycle" />
   <use x="150" y="250" fill="green" xlink:href="#bicycle" />   
</svg>
```

Comment: я почистил комменты

Answer (score 6):

Это очень просто:

Вставьте свою иконку `<svg>` в другой SVG. Установите `x`, `y`, `width` и `height` встроенного элемента `<svg>` в соответствии с размером и положением квадратной области, в которой вы хотите разместить иконку. И SVG сделает все остальное (включая центрирование).

В этом случае я выбрал квадрат: `x = "6"` `y = "6"` `width = "20"` `height = "20"`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="45">
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" width="154.5%" height="509.1%" x="-27.3%" y="-204.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(1 1)">
    <ellipse cx="15" cy="37.467" fill="#999" fill-opacity=".9" filter="url(#a)" rx="11" ry="1.467"/>
    <path fill="#006893" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#006893" d="M15 0C6.448 0 0 6.759 0 15.726c0 11.28 13.944 21.44 14.537 21.867.138.1.302.149.463.149a.784.784 0 0 0 .463-.15C16.055 37.167 30 27.007 30 15.727 30 6.76 23.552 0 15 0z"/>
  </g>

  <svg x="6" y="6" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="#fff"><title>bicycle</title><path d="M5.5,6.137a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H6.909a.249.249,0,0,1,.231.156l.637,1.568a.251.251,0,0,1-.036.25l-.35.437a.25.25,0,0,1-.3.07A4.894,4.894,0,0,0,5,10.137a5,5,0,1,0,4.856,6.19.25.25,0,0,1,.243-.19h.4a1,1,0,0,0,.807-.409l4.281-5.837a.247.247,0,0,1,.236-.1.252.252,0,0,1,.2.161l.281.762a.251.251,0,0,1-.095.293,4.978,4.978,0,1,0,2.79-.87,3.824,3.824,0,0,0-.549.046.25.25,0,0,1-.27-.161L16.92,6.6a.249.249,0,0,1,.174-.329l1.742-.435a1,1,0,0,0-.485-1.941L15.8,4.532a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.042,1.974l.08.217a.253.253,0,0,1-.008.193.25.25,0,0,1-.142.129L9.764,8.8a.251.251,0,0,1-.316-.141l-.113-.279A.178.178,0,0,1,9.5,8.137a1,1,0,0,0,0-2Zm-.5,12a3,3,0,1,1,2.658-4.364.25.25,0,0,1-.222.364H5a1,1,0,0,0,0,2H7.436a.25.25,0,0,1,.222.364A2.985,2.985,0,0,1,5,18.137Zm5.049-4.076a.1.1,0,0,1-.174-.036,4.941,4.941,0,0,0-.927-1.916.249.249,0,0,1,0-.309l.609-.761a.252.252,0,0,1,.111-.08L12.5,9.95a.25.25,0,0,1,.286.383ZM19,18.137a3,3,0,0,1-3-3,2.959,2.959,0,0,1,.8-2.022.249.249,0,0,1,.417.084l.842,2.284a1,1,0,1,0,1.876-.692l-.964-2.617a.028.028,0,0,1,0-.025A.028.028,0,0,1,19,12.137a3,3,0,0,1,0,6Z"/></svg>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420593/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>